# Difference between `or` comparisons that repeat the variable vs. ones that don't

Tags: python, variables, if-statement

I'm curious what's the reason for the different results from the two samples below (just `or` without variable `GPA` and `or` with variable `GPA`)?

```
GPA = input('Enter GPA Grade: ')
if  GPA == 'A+' or 'a+' or 'A' or 'a':
    print('5.0')
```

The code above always make same output '5.0' no matter what kind of input we enter.

```
GPA = input('Enter GPA Grade: ')
if  GPA == 'A+' or GPA == 'a+' or GPA == 'A' or GPA == 'a':
    print('5.0')
```

The code above make the correct output  when we type the variable GPA after `or`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that the outputs are different is that the first example checks whether the strings `"a+"`, `"A"`, or `"a"` are true, NOT whether `GPA` is equal to them.

For example, if you wrote:

```
if "a":
    print("Success")
```

`"Success"` would be printed because `"a"` is "technically true" (more correctly, it's "truthy"). Contrastingly, if you wrote:

```
if "":
    print("Success")
```

Nothing would be printed because the empty string is "falsy." Other things that are falsy include `0` and `[]` (empty list).

In your first example:

```
GPA = input('Enter GPA Grade: ')
if GPA == 'A+' or 'a+' or 'A' or 'a':
   print('5.0')
```

`5.0` is always printed because the interpreter simplifies the `if` code like this:

```
if (GPA == 'A+') or ('a+') or ('A') or ('a')
```

This way, the expression will always evaluate to `True` because of the truthy strings:

```
if (GPA == 'A+') or True or True or True
```

So no matter what the GPA is, the `or`s will simplify to just True.

The second example works as expected because you are testing each equality case separately. Another shorter solution uses the `in` operator, which tests if an element is *in* a list:

```
GPA = input('Enter GPA Grade: ')
if GPA in ['a', 'A', 'a+', 'A+']:
    print('5.0')
```

Even better, using the `str.lower()` method:

```
GPA = input('Enter GPA Grade: ')
if GPA.lower() in ['a', 'a+']:
    print('5.0')
```